# How complex should interfaces be?

Tags: c#, interface

We are working in a project where there will be a shared configuration which needs to be accessed by multiple parts of the solution.

The team responsible for the Config module implemented an interface which consists only of 2 classes. 2 classes that are responsible for getting, caching and providing the particular values (via properties).

I feel that this is a bad design, in my opinion, it would be better to define all the config values one may access via the interface, but not actual classes that implement this behaviour.

In my opinion, for something like getting config values, it would be more logical to give an interface that shows me what values I will be able to access, but not a class (which implementation e.g. the properties is not controlled by the interface).

**-edit-**
The Interface looks like this:

```
public interface IConfigurationResolver
{
    GeneralConfiguration GetGeneralConfiguration(string Id);
    SpecificConfiguration GetSpecificConfiguration(string Id);
}
```

It is implemented by one class. What I meant is that this interfaces really just defines two classes that are each responsible for providing the configuration values, whereas I think it would be better if the interface did not care about such details and should provide the config values itself

These are very experienced developers, whereas I am not, so what is your stand on this?

Comment: It's almost impossible to comment on this without a broader understanding of the application: size, function, life-cycle, and so on. These all factors that can impact what is considered best practice. Maintainability is less important for a product with a short life-cycle than long-term, for example. The developers' efforts would be better spent on things other than the configuration classes.

Comment: Configuration is actually very important in this project. It is a web application that will be running for at least 5 years (maybe much longer). It will enable the user to work on different (but very similar) systems. These systems will need a lot of parameters and formulars which vary from system to system and may change over time. Sorry I can't really say what exactly we are talking about here

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things going on here…

The reference of non-abstract classes in the `IConfigurationResolver` interface is a code smell, violating the “program to an interface, not an implementation” principal ([What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)).

Your desire to explicitly reveal the configuration parameters through an interface is a good one, and is in accordance with the notion of an *Intention Revealing Interface* (as discussed in Eric Evans’ [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)).

However, if you have a great many configuration values, this interface could end up having a great many methods on it.  This is where knowledge of your domain comes in – the decomposition of the “universe of configurations” in to a set of cohesive interfaces, each of which are used to configure a separate aspect of your application is a skill in itself, and relates to the ‘I’ in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).  Lowy’s [Programming .NET components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102070) discusses the issue of contract re-factoring, and as a rough guide suggests aiming for 3-5 methods per interface.

I’m guessing the desire to "re-factor the configurations" is the root of the existence of the two methods on the current interface.

Answer (score 0):

One of the SOLID principles is 
Interface segregation principle
“many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.”

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29

What do you mean by "interface which consists only of 2 classes"? That only two classes implement this interface?

> I feel that this is a bad design, in my opinion, it would be better to
>   define all the config values one may access via the interface, but not
>   actual classes that implement this behaviour.

Not sure I understand your question - Yes you should refer to the interface and not directly the class?

Comment: I think there is no violation of this principle as the configuration can be seen as a granular entity in our case. It does not make much sense to split it, because all values could be accessed at any place.

Comment: Ok - fair enough. I don't fully understand your question as the title was how complex should the interface be but the body of your questions implies you are asking should you refer to the interface rather than the class? Can you give some more info about the problem

Comment: Your edit is clearer now. It's swings and roundabout imo without knowing what and how many properties are on the two classes.

Comment: Something around 40 right now (this might change over the years). But they are very similar and will contain either general config, parameters or formulas

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with that approach. One OO principle is hiding. As long as the inner structure of the class(es) is hidden with private methods or subclasses, there is no need to use any interface at all.

Interfaces make sense as soon as you want to provide multiple implementations for a sinlge behaviour (like the Bean Validation API) or if you want to restrict the methods which should be available to different users of a class.